# Failed to receive Email alerts on HP ILO 4

Tags: email, hp, ilo, alerts

I have trouble getting email alerts on one of the HP server DL380 Gen9 on windows server2012 R2
We dont have exchange Server in our Environment.

I tried enabling ILO AlertMail with my Email address 
[image]

Is there something wrong with my settings?

I didnt tried with SNMP Settings, do i need to configure SNMP first ?
[image]

If yes please suggest me how do i configure just to get mail alerts on any **Hardware Failure**.

License Type    iLO 4 Advanced

iLO Firmware Version    2.30 Aug 19 2015

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the ILO4 will relay to Gmail for you. It's a very simple mailer. Notice how there's no way to authenticate against Google/gmail.

If you want the full suite of HP alerts available, you should install and configure the HP SNMP agents on your Windows server and handle your SMTP auth/relay within the OS.

Comment: Then there is nothing we can do with ILO Alert Mail settings? :/

Comment: Not without a server you don't have to authenticate against.

Answer (score 0):

Google will work, you need to use   - aspmx.l.google.com 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en